# How do I stop Sitecore redirecting to the login page for certain URL's

Tags: authentication, sitecore

I can't seem to find specific information on this one;

We have a url that has a '/forgottenpassword/' url. When navigating to it, it auto redirects to the /login page the first time you go there. It then generates the anonymous user and allows me to navigate to the 'forgottenpassword' url.

Is there a way (without disabling the requiresLogin) feature to put some pages within a 'DMZ' almost?

Allowing users to navigate to forgottenPassword the first time?

Many thanks

Comment: This is Sitecore 8

Answer (score 3):

You have to give **read** permission to `extranet\anonymous` user as it is assigned to any unauthenticated visitor browsing your Sitecore website.

Speaking from experience, it might be that you will just need to remove "deny read permission" for `extranet\anonymous` user for your forgotten password page.